# Using String for Referral Program iOS

Tags: ios, udid

I'm trying to create a campaign where a user can apply a credit to their device. I want to prevent account creation spamming by returning a unique string that will never change regardless of whether a user deletes the app, etc.

What is the best practice way of achieving this? I found the `ASIdentifierManager` class but that doesn't seem appropriate (as apps are rejected for including this class without actually including ad support supposedly). `identifierForVendor` from `UIDevice` class changes upon every app deletion, which seems useless to me.

This doesn't have to be the device's actual UDID, or the same across other apps, just a string that stays constant regardless of app deletion and reinstallation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to write a `UUID` to the keychain. That will survive app deletion.

Comment: Thanks, I know this is the generally accepted answer but technically a user could wipe their phone and start fresh. Unlikely but it would be nice if Apple generated a random unique string per device that is different across each app in the same way Facebook's iOS SDK's facebook_id returned by a user is unique to one app.